# Name for subgroup of elements commuting with another group action

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, terminology, group-actions

Let groups $G$ and $H$ act on a set $X$. Then
$$
\{g\in G\mid \forall x\in X, h\in H: ghx = hgx\} \le G
$$
is a subgroup of $G$.

> Does this subgroup have a name, or any particular significance?

This is just a question out of curiousity.

---

**Context:** View the action by $H$ as a functor $F:\mathbf{B}H\to \mathbf{Set}$ from the one-object group category $\mathbf{B}H$. Then my subgroup is the set of elements $g\in G$ such that $(x\mapsto gx)$ is a natural transformation $F\Rightarrow F$.

This came up randomly in a calculation, but may allude to there being some importance to this subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the intersection of $G$ and $\text{Aut}_H(X)$. That's also what your natural transformation computation says.

Comment: Thanks, but what is $Aut_H(X)$ exactly? Automorphisms of $X$ given by the action of an $h$?

Comment: It's the group of automorphisms of $X$ as an $H$-set; formally, bijections $f : X \to X$ such that $f(hx) = h f(x)$ for all $h \in H, x \in X$. Generally there is a category of $H$-sets and morphisms $f : X \to Y$ between $H$-sets are functions satisfying $f(hx) = h f(x)$; these are the same thing as natural transformations between functors $BH \to \text{Set}$, so this is the functor category $[BH, \text{Set}]$.

Comment: To perhaps getting some insight, let's consider the particular case $H\le G$. Call $\phi$ the action. Then:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\{g\in G\mid \forall x\in X, h\in H: ghx = hgx\} &= \{g\in G\mid \forall h\in H, \forall x\in X: [g,h]x = x\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid \forall h\in H, \forall x\in X: [g,h]\in\operatorname{Stab}(x)\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid \forall h\in H: [g,h]\in\operatorname{ker}\phi\} \\
\end{alignat}

Comment: Sorry, that was meant as a comment for @Milten, ... I should have had place it below the OP.

Comment: Thanks (and pardon the late response). To spell it out a bit more for future readers, this answer also shows that the soubgroup in question is indeed and evidently a subgroup. Action by $G$ defines a homomorphism $\phi:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ with image, say, $K$. Then our set is $\phi^{-1}\left(K\cap \mathrm{Aut}_H(X)\right)\le G$.